# Trigonometric identity problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\frac{\sin(2x)}{2 \sin (x)}-\frac{\cos(2x)}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}=\sin(x).$$
I got it on a test and want an answer. I always hit a dead end with the identities I learned.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic mathematics. It is better suited for [math.se]

Comment: Do you know the double-angle formulas?

Comment: Comment: Note that the left side is not defined at $x=0$, while the right side is. By the rules of the trig identities game, one is supposed not to notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$, and $\cos(2x) = \cos^{2}(x) - \sin^{2}(x)$, which factors as $(\cos(x) - \sin(x))(\cos(x) + \sin(x))$. That turns your identity into $$ \frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{2\sin(x)} - \frac{\cos^{2}(x) - \sin^{2}(x)}{\cos(x) + \sin(x)} = \cos(x) - (\cos(x) - \sin(x)) = \sin(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

1. Use $\sin(2x) = 2 \sin(x) \cos(x).$
2. Use $\cos(2x) = \cos^2 (x) - \sin^2(x).$
3. Factor $\cos^2 (x) - \sin^2(x) = (\cos(x) + \sin(x))(\cos (x) - \sin(x)).$